# Python - How to calculate the sum of sales for the last 2 days from a given date column?

Tags: python, loops, date, sum, group

A pandas dataframe df_sales is populated as shown below. For each ID, there are multiple dates, all grouped & sorted in the order shown prior to the problem.

```
ID      Date            Sales
a       01/01/2020      20
a       02/01/2020      65
a       03/01/2020      31
b       01/01/2020      25
b       02/01/2020      15
b       03/01/2020      42
c       01/01/2020      31
c       02/01/2020      50
c       03/01/2020      25
```

Now, I would like to see sum of last 2 days sales sales in the same dataframe as shown below.

```
ID      Date            Sales   Sales in last 2 days
a       01/01/2020      20       20
a       02/01/2020      65       85
a       03/01/2020      31       96
b       01/01/2020      25       25
b       02/01/2020      15       40
b       03/01/2020      42       57
c       01/01/2020      31       31
c       02/01/2020      50       81
c       03/01/2020      25       75
```

Could you please suggest how could this be possible? Many thanks in advance.

I tried grouping and aggregating however I couldn't iterate on the last 2 days alone, especially when there was no previous date value.

Comment: check out this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand correctly, tried using [Shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get previous row value to sum and create a new column named 'Sales in last 2 days'

```
import pandas as pd

id_col = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']

date_rng = ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03',\
    '2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03']
sales = [20,65,31,25,15,29,23,5,65]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':id_col, 'Date':date_rng, 'Sales':sales})
id_grp = df.groupby(['ID'])
df_list = []

for df_grp in id_grp:
    df_grp[1]['Sales in last 2 days'] = df_grp[1]['Sales'] + df_grp[1]['Sales'].shift().fillna(0)
    df_list.append(df_grp[1])

print(pd.concat(df_list))
```

Comment: Hello Vignesh, fantastic. This worked. May I know what should be done if you need to consider 3 days instead of only 2 days?

Comment: please check [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) may be useful